# matplotlib LogFormatterExponent -- 'e' in the exponent labels of cbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm modifying someone else's library to setup a cbar with log (values). I thought I could use LogFormatterExponent() ... But it seemingly randomly adds and 'e' to the exponents that it uses for the cbar. What's going on? How can I suppress/fix this?

> ```
>     if show_cbar:
>         if log:
>             l_f = LogFormatterExponent()
>         else:
>             l_f = ScalarFormatter()
>         if qtytitle is not None:
>             plt.colorbar(ims,format=l_f).set_label(qtytitle)
>         else:
>             plt.colorbar(ims,format=l_f).set_label(units)
> ```

Here's what I'm seeing for log=True:

[image]

And another plot where log = False:

[image]

At first, I thought the 'e's were being cut-off by the label at right... but over several plots this doesn't appear to be the case. I usually get 1-2 'e's ... But on a plot with only 3 color bar ticks, I see none!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cm
import matplotlib.ticker as ct

data = np.exp(np.random.rand(20, 20) * 100)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
log_norm = cm.LogNorm()

im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap='viridis', norm=log_norm)
fig.colorbar(im, format=ct.LogFormatterExponent())
```

This looks like a bug in mpl.  If you already have a large library, I would just include a fixed version of the formatter.

```
class LogFormatterExponentFixed(LogFormatter):
    """
    Format values for log axis; using ``exponent = log_base(value)``
    """

    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        """Return the format for tick val *x* at position *pos*"""

        vmin, vmax = self.axis.get_view_interval()
        vmin, vmax = mtransforms.nonsingular(vmin, vmax, expander=0.05)
        d = abs(vmax - vmin)
        b = self._base
        if x == 0:
            return '0'
        sign = np.sign(x)
        # only label the decades
        fx = math.log(abs(x)) / math.log(b)
        isDecade = is_close_to_int(fx)
        if not isDecade and self.labelOnlyBase:
            s = ''
        elif abs(fx) > 10000:
            s = '%1.0g' % fx
        elif abs(fx) < 1:
            s = '%1.0g' % fx
        else:
            # this is the added line
            fd = math.log(abs(d)) / math.log(b)
            s = self.pprint_val(fx, fd)
        if sign == -1:
            s = '-%s' % s

        return self.fix_minus(s)
```

Working on a [fix for upstream](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5594).

Comment: Thx... yea, that's 'almost' what I did. I just created a custom formatter for exponents -- taking log of the values -- and used that. Thx for confirming the issue.